# CSS centering when using display block

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have some buttons that I want to vertically and horizontally align within a div, and also to stack ontop of each other as opposed to side by side

In my CSS I can only seem to get them to align, or stack, but not both. Whats the correct way to do this?

HTML:

```
<div id="sidePanel">
  <div id="buttonContainer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Apple</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Apple</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Apple</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="itemList">
  item list
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#itemList {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: green;
}

#sidePanel {
  float: right;
  width: 300px;
  background: red;
}

#buttonContainer {
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

#buttonContainer button {
  display: block;
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gjher92t/

Comment: Could you please expand on what you're trying to do "In my CSS I can only seem to get them to align, or stack, but not both"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean you want them to both stack and align?

If you change the display to `inline-block` they will stack when there's enough of them to fill the container...

```css
#itemList {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: green;
}

#sidePanel {
  float: right;
  width: 300px;
  background: red;
}

#buttonContainer {
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

#buttonContainer button {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidePanel">
  <div id="buttonContainer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Apple</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Apple</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Apple</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Apple</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Apple</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Apple</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Apple</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Apple</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Apple</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Apple</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Apple</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="itemList">
  item list
</div>
```

Or change the `text-align` property of the container to align them left, rather than center...

```css
#itemList {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: green;
}

#sidePanel {
  float: right;
  width: 300px;
  background: red;
}

#buttonContainer {
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: left;
}

#buttonContainer button {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidePanel">
  <div id="buttonContainer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Apple</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Apple</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Apple</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Apple</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Apple</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Apple</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Apple</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Apple</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Apple</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Apple</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Apple</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="itemList">
  item list
</div>
```

Or add `margin: 0 auto` to have them stack in the middle of the container:

```css
#itemList {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: green;
}

#sidePanel {
  float: right;
  width: 300px;
  background: red;
}

#buttonContainer {
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

#buttonContainer button {
  display: block;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidePanel">
  <div id="buttonContainer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Apple</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Apple</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Apple</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Apple</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Apple</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Apple</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Apple</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Apple</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Apple</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Apple</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Apple</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="itemList">
  item list
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `margin: auto;` for center alignment.

```css
#itemList {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: green;
}
#sidePanel {
  float: right;
  width: 300px;
  background: red;
}
#buttonContainer {
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
#buttonContainer button {
  display: block;
   margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidePanel">
  <div id="buttonContainer">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Apple</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Apple</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Apple</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="itemList">
  item list
</div>
```